# How can I lint C++ code to find all unused return values?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I would like to statically inspect all calls to non-void functions where the return value is not used.

In effect this would be like applying [`__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) to all non-void functions, but of course for a large project that is not practical to do.

Is there any static analysis tool that can provide this information?

Comment: compile with `gcc -Wall` , you are gonna get warnings for all those occurances

Comment: @Roi No, you won't get any warnings about that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth What is this then `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: That's not an unused return value, it's no value being returned. The two things are completely different.

Comment: @RoiHatam That's something different. That when the function itself forget to return a value. What we have here is when the caller of the function doesn't use its returned value.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thank you

Comment: @Galik Thank you I misread.

Comment: If you need this ability for only 1 language, what would it be: C or C++?  I suspect posting for only 1 language would have prevented a DV.

Comment: I'd rather not speculate about why someone downvoted :) I am specifically interested in both C and C++ for this question.

Comment: It's easy enough to set up an example program to test on -- even one that is written in the common subset of C and C++.  Having done so, I can tell you that no combination of warning options causes either `gcc` or `g++` to warn about unused function results for functions without the `warn_unused_result` attribute.  (As judged by enabling *all* warnings.)

Comment: That's quite useless. For `printf` for example one typically does not test the result and there are a lot of other functions one does not use the result, although they return one. "but of course for a large project that is not practical to do." - That's a wrong presumption. It is of course the best and correct way to do so! Why do you assume it is not possible? For a single function one knows best if the result is more "informative" or always has to be checked.

Comment: I'm aware that one typically doesn't check the return value of `printf`, but that doesn't mean it's a useless thing to check: "Upon successful return, these functions return the  number  of  characters  printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings). [...] If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned." (from the man page)

Comment: voted to reopen, this question is the opposite of "too broad"

Comment: Why not try to use static analizer such as cppcheck or pvs-studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`clang-query`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/tree/master/clang-query).  Here is a shell script that invokes `clang-query` to find calls that return a value that is not used:

```
#!/bin/sh
# cmd.sh: Run clang-query to report unused return values.

# When --dump, print the AST of matching syntax.
if [ "x$1" = "x--dump" ]; then
  dump="set output dump"
  shift
fi

query='m
  callExpr(
    isExpansionInMainFile(),
    hasParent(anyOf(
      compoundStmt(),
      ifStmt(hasCondition(expr().bind("cond"))),
      whileStmt(hasCondition(expr().bind("cond"))),
      doStmt(hasCondition(expr().bind("cond")))
    )),
    unless(hasType(voidType())),
    unless(isTypeDependent()),
    unless(cxxOperatorCallExpr()),
    unless(callee(namedDecl(anyOf(
      hasName("memset"),
      hasName("setlength"),
      hasName("flags"),
      hasName("width"),
      hasName("__builtin_memcpy")
    )))),
    unless(equalsBoundNode("cond")))'

clang-query -c="$dump" -c="$query" "$@"
```

To run this on, say, `test1.cc`:

```
$ ./cmd.sh test1.cc --
```

The basic idea of the query is to look for call expressions whose immediate parent is a compound statement.  That is expanded to handle an immediate parent that is a control flow statement, being careful not to report when the call appears as the conditional expression.

Some other complications the query deals with:

- This only reports in the main file of a translation unit in order to eliminate the voluminous noise from headers.  Remove the `isExpansionInMainFile` filter to drink from the fire hose.
- In C++ templates, we might not know what the type is, so suppress reporting all calls with dependent types.
- Some functions like `memset` have useless or only rarely useful return values.  They have to be filtered out to see any useful signal.  The list of function names in the query is just the tip of that iceberg.
- C++ overloaded operators, including `operator<<` and `operator=`, usually return a value, but that value is most often ignored.  So suppress reports for all overloaded operators.

I've tested this lightly (with `clang-query` from clang+llvm-8.0.1) on some files in a utility library of mine, which is how I found some of the things that need to be filtered out for this to be useful.  There are probably many more things that need filtering, depending on your application.

The query language is described at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html .  See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57967563/2659307) for some more links and information about `clang-query`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for providing a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cppcheck is a command-line tool that tries to detect bugs that your C/C++ compiler doesn't see, it also includes a web based report generator.

Comment: AFAIK cppcheck doesn't detect this type of bug

Answer (score 0):

I think there are software can do this like `DevExtreme` and in  `social.msdn.microsoft.com` in the answer for this question  `how-to-get-a-warning-for-an-unused-return-value?` they mention that Premium and Ultimate versions of visual studio has some tools.

Read this:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4355715a-5af7-4a2b-8aa0-bc2112eaa911/how-to-get-a-warning-for-an-unused-return-value?forum=vclanguage

and this `mandatory-error-codes-revisited` from: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mandatory-error-codes-revisited/191601612