# Writing a specific Clang-tidy check to avoid passing an expression into std::vector::reserve()

Tags: c++, static-analysis, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

In our codebase, we always use `std::vector::reserve()` to achieve higher performance. Most of the time they work well.

Also, sometimes we might pass an expression into the `reserve()` function.
For example,

```
const double length = GetLength();
const double step = GetStep();
v.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(length / step));
```

However, due to some algorithm bugs, `length` might be a `negative number`, and it's almost impossible to know this problem without running the program. Every time this problem happens, it will through an error and then a crash is inevitable:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
terminate called recursively
  what():  vector::reserve
```

Fortunately, We are now using clang-tidy, so I'm wondering if I can apply some custom rules like `avoid passing an expression into std::vector::reserve() function` and manually check every variable if it might overflow.

Is there a way to write a clang-tidy rule to do this?

Comment: You can't pass expressions, only results of expressions. And even using a separate variable is *still* technically an expression. A much better solution is to do input validation, and fix the actual bugs instead.

Comment: Totally agree with you. The reason I want to perform a clang-tidy checker on that is to notify the authors `you are doing something really dangerous` and let them do the input validation in their merge requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll have to decide exactly what you want reported.  For simplicity, I am interpreting your question as wanting to report any call to `std::vector::reserve` where the argument is not an **identifier**.

Next, the core of any `clang-tidy` check is the [AST matcher](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) expression.  The tool `clang-query` can be used to directly run an AST matcher against a given input program, so I'll use that to show such a matcher.  (Incorporating that matcher into a `clang-tidy` check is then done the like any other, as described in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html).)

So, here is a command that runs `clang-query` on the file `reserve1.cc` and reports all calls to `std::vector::reserve` whose argument is not an identifier:

```
clang-query -c='m
  callExpr(
    callee(
      cxxMethodDecl(
        matchesName("std::vector<.*>::reserve")
      )),
    unless(
      hasArgument(0,
        expr(declRefExpr())
      ))
  )' \
  reserve1.cc --
```

The matcher expression is fairly self-explanatory except for `declRefExpr`, which is the matcher that matches identifiers, which Clang terms "declaration references".

When the above command is run on the following input:

```
// reserve1.cc
// Example for a check that the 'reserve' argument is "simple".
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859738/writing-a-specific-clang-tidy-check-to-avoid-passing-an-expression-into-stdvec

#include <vector>

double GetLength();
double GetStep();
void bad()
{
  const double length = GetLength();
  const double step = GetStep();
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(length / step));   // reported
}

void good(std::size_t len)
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(len);                                       // not reported
}

struct Other {
  void reserve(int);
};
void irrelevant(Other o, int x)
{
  o.reserve(x + x);                                     // not reported
}

// EOF
```

It prints:

```
Match #1:

/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/reserve-argument/reserve1.cc:14:3: note: "root"
      binds here
  v.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(length / step));   // reported
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.
```

I recommend spending some time interactively testing and tweaking the AST matcher expression using `clang-query` on your program of interest before doing the additional work of embedding it into `clang-tidy`.

There is a bit more information about `clang-query` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57967563/2659307) of mine that answers a vaguely similar question.

Comment: What a comprehensive and helpful answer. Really appreciate it!